# User Azure AD groups in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, azure, ad

We have an education license office 365 and i can create groups in AD azure portal (Microsoft).

but in SharePoint I can see users but not groups

anybody can help me to see groups (created in azure portal) directly in SharePoint?

thanks for any help

Comment: That should work. Make sure you're creating security groups and not Exchange groups.